# Clustal Omega in Command Line

Tags: alignment, bioinformatics, sequence-alignment, clustal

Below is what I am getting when I type ./configure on terminal while inside the clustal omega package.

```
 Welcome to Clustal Omega - version 1.2.1 (AndreaGiacomo)

                       +NMMMMMMMMMS=
                    MMMMM?      :MMMMM8
                  IMMMMS           MMMMM,
                ~MMMMN              ,MMMMM
               =MMMMM                 MMMMM
              ?MMMMM                  +MMMMM
              MMMMMS                   MMMMM
              MMMMM                    MMMMM:
              MMMMM                    MMMMM+
              MMMMM                    MMMMM~
              MMMMM                    MMMMM
              MMMMMZ                   MMMMM
               MMMMM                  ,MMMMZ
                MMMM8                 MMMM+
                 MMMMS               MMMM,
                   MMMMO           MMMM
            ,N       SMMM        MMM8       +8
            ,M7         M+       M+        :M8
            ,MMMMMMMMMMMMI       MMMMMMMMMMMM8
            ,MMMMMMMMMMMM8       MMMMMMMMMMMM8
            ,MMMMMMMMMMMMN       MMMMMMMMMMMM8


checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin13.4.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin13.4.0
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 196608
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking for /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... no
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ar... ar
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm output from gcc object... ok
checking for dsymutil... dsymutil
checking for nmedit... nmedit
checking for lipo... lipo
checking for otool... otool
checking for otool64... no
checking for -single_module linker flag... yes
checking for -exported_symbols_list linker flag... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... yes
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fno-common -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fno-common -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... no
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin13.4.0 dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking dependency style of g++... (cached) gcc3
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for ld used by g++... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking whether the g++ linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fno-common -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fno-common -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... no
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin13.4.0 dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking assert.h usability... yes
checking assert.h presence... yes
checking for assert.h... yes
checking ctype.h usability... yes
checking ctype.h presence... yes
checking for ctype.h... yes
checking float.h usability... yes
checking float.h presence... yes
checking for float.h... yes
checking limits.h usability... yes
checking limits.h presence... yes
checking for limits.h... yes
checking math.h usability... yes
checking math.h presence... yes
checking for math.h... yes
checking for memory.h... (cached) yes
checking stdarg.h usability... yes
checking stdarg.h presence... yes
checking for stdarg.h... yes
checking stdio.h usability... yes
checking stdio.h presence... yes
checking for stdio.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking time.h usability... yes
checking time.h presence... yes
checking for time.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking for log in -lm... yes
checking for log2 in -lm... yes
checking argtable2.h usability... yes
checking argtable2.h presence... yes
checking for argtable2.h... yes
checking for arg_parse in -largtable2... yes
checking for OpenMP flag of C compiler... unknown
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking for ntohs... yes
checking for ntohl... yes
checking for ntons... no
checking for ntonl... no
checking size of unsigned short... 2
checking size of unsigned int... 4
checking size of unsigned long... 8
checking size of unsigned long long... 8
checking for stroul... no
checking for strtoull... yes
checking for ftello... yes
checking for fseeko... yes
checking for ftello64... no
checking for fseeko64... no
checking for ftell64... no
checking for fseek64... no
checking for off_t... yes
checking size of fpos_t... 8
checking if malloc debugging is wanted... no
checking whether to build with debug information... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating clustalo.pc
config.status: creating Doxyfile
config.status: creating src/clustal/Makefile
config.status: creating src/hhalign/Makefile
config.status: creating src/kmpp/Makefile
config.status: creating src/squid/Makefile
config.status: creating src/config.h
config.status: src/config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing src/clustal-omega-config.h commands
config.status: creating src/clustal-omega-config.h - prefix CLUSTAL_OMEGA for src/config.h defines
config.status: src/clustal-omega-config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
```

then, when I "make", I am getting,

```
Making all in src
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
Making all in hhalign
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in squid
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in kmpp
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in clustal
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
```

It must work fine when I type "make" so I move on and install the clustal omega. But that was what I have been getting. Please tell me what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After typing the make command you must type

```
make install
```

Assuming you have all of the correct dependencies installed, namely argtable2.h, this should install clustal omega for you.

Comment: When I type the make install,the command line prints out an error. Making install in src
Making install in hhalign
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
test -z "/usr/local/include/clustalo/hhalign" || ../.././install-sh -c -d "/usr/local/include/clustalo/hhalign"
mkdir: /usr/local/include/clustalo: Permission denied
mkdir: /usr/local/include/clustalo: No such file or directory
make[3]: *** [install-library_includeHEADERS] Error 1
make[2]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1

Answer (score 2):

Does the program open if you type

```
clustal
```

At the command line?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. I CAN NOW USE CLUSTAL OMEGA ON MY COMMAND LINE!